# Possible to call a method on a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to do

```
current_user.posts.do_changes_and_return_collection
```

instead of

```
Post.where(user_id: current_user.id).do_changes_and_return_collection
```

and work on the collection inside the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like this on Post model:

```
 def self.do_changes_and_return_collection
   update_all(deleted: false) # Just an example.
   where(submited: true)
 end
```

And you can call: `submiteds = current_user.posts.do_changes_and_return_collection`

Note: `update_all` won't trigger validations and callbacks

Edit: To get the relation owner
In `User` you will have to extend the has_many relationship:

```
has_many :posts do
  def owner
    proxy_association.owner
  end
end
```

And calling `current_user.posts.owner` you will get current_user

Comment: Do you know if there's any ActiveRecord-way to get the parent object holding the collection within the method (i.e. the `current_user`)? 
`self.first.user` works I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it's possible.for that you have to use `scope`.

Ex.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :do_changes_and_return_collection, -> { where(active: true) }
end
```

then you can call:

```
Post.where(user_id: current_user.id).do_changes_and_return_collection
```

Please refer [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)